# Dev Component Can't update Tools during design

Tags: vb.net, controls

I have a big problem in my `vb.net`.

I created application using `vb.net` and `Dev` component, it was working 100%, but after I upgraded my operating system from `Windows 8 pro` to `Windows 8.1 pro`, `VS2012` and `dev` component installed I faced a big problem.

I can't use the GUI to edit most of control during design, its looks like it is a part of the form, and can't be selected, as per the below photo.

And for new controls on new forms (Dev Forms) it can't appear in form to be edited, it shown in the bottom area as per the below photo

Comment: Have you checked the Dev component's home page to see if there's an update?

Comment: No, but I solved the problem, I'm using VS2012 and dev11, I installed dev12 the I installed 11 again it solved. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I have only Dev Ver.11 full:
1. Un-install Dev Ver.11
2. Install last dev trial ver12.
3. Open VS2012.
4. Uninstall dev ver.12
5. Re-install dev Ver.11 again, activate, enjoy.